# Count duplicate columns in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

How do you count the DUPLICATE columns in a database table using eloquent model querying?

For example, in SQL, there's this command:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(email) 
FROM users
GROUP BY email 
HAVING ( COUNT(email) > 1 )
```

The code above will return the names from all columns with similar email addresses.

What I'm trying to achieve is to get the COUNT of duplicate entries, i.e.

```
$noOfjobsFromSameCustomers = App\Workflow::count();
```

But I need an additional parameter to specify that the cust_id (a column in the workflows table) is duplicated, something like:

```
$noOfjobsFromSameCustomers = App\Workflow::notDistinct()->orderBy('cust_id')->count();
```

For example, given the table below:

```
 ID  NAME EMAIL 
 1   John asd@asd.com 
 2   Sam  asd@asd.com 
 3   Tom  asd@asd.com 
 4   Bob  bob@asd.com 
 5   Tom  asd@asd.com
```

How can I count the number of times a specified email address (e.g. asd@asd.com) recurs?

Comment: Not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Just use "where" and "count" : App\Whatever::where('email','asd@asd.com')->count();

Comment: Thanks! I think I can work this is in somehow as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **havingRow** :

```
->havingRaw('COUNT(<columneName>) > 1')
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get this by raw query

```
$result = DB::select( DB::raw(" select * from (
  SELECT name, COUNT(email) as e_count
  FROM users
  GROUP BY email 
  )a where  a.e_count > 1 ");
```

and put your where condition in this query 
Please see for more [Larave website](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions)